# How to inject Spring dependencies into Message Driven EJB?

Tags: java, spring, ejb

Is there a way how to inject Spring dependencies into Message Driven EJB?
The bean:

```
@MessageDriven( ......)
public class MessageBean implements MessageListener {       

     @Autowired private someDAO; // <-how to wire a Spring managed bean here?

     public void onMessage(Message message) {

              TextMessage textMsg = (TextMessage)message;
              try { someDAO.persist(message); //handle message, save to DB } 
              catch(Exception e) {}
     }
...........
```

Comment: I'd use either Spring or EJB 3, but not both together.  Why can't you use EJB injection to add that DAO?

Answer (score 0):

If you must spring, provides an annotation to support DI on non-managed beans.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

As duffymo said, i'd also use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- use [SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ejb/interceptor/SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.html), this requires at least Spring 2.5.1 and EJB 3
- if you're on JBoss 5 or higher you can use the [snowdrop spring deployer](http://docs.jboss.org/snowdrop/2.0.0.Final/html/ch03.html#d0e618)
- if you use JBoss Seam 3.1 or higher you can use [Seam Spring](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/spring/latest/reference/en-US/html/)